# how to validate testnet and mainnet bitcoin address via online api or offline for Android App?

Tags: blockchain, address, android

I would like to know web api provider to validate Mainnet & Testet3 Bitcoin Address.

[How to validate a Bitcoin address is a real one?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2564/how-to-validate-a-bitcoin-address-is-a-real-one)

[Validate bitcoin address from android application](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13779/validate-bitcoin-address-from-android-application)

Gone through above references but Want a web service provider or local bitcoinJ type java library class.

Answer (score 2):

### **Here are list of references to validate mainnet and testnet Bitcoin addresses:**

### **Offline**

**IN JAVA**

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitcoin/address_validation#Java (mainnet + testnet)

https://github.com/timqi/btc_address_validator/blob/master/BTCAddrValidator.java (mainnet only)

**IN GO**

https://github.com/niksmac/btc-validate/blob/master/src/btc-validate.go

**IN PHP**

https://github.com/niksmac/btc-validate/blob/master/src/btc-validate.php

**IN RUBY**

https://github.com/niksmac/btc-validate/blob/master/src/btc-validate.rb

### **Online Api**

https://blockexplorer.com/api/addr-validate/mjdkX5oxbc9ioTmbnRtc5g4Cojyr5esUuZ (mainnet + testnet)

***Note:*** For **around 30 languages** we can take benefit of same by following reference:

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitcoin/address_validation